# Need to Change Alternate Apple ID on the apple id screen

Tags: apple-id

Can you change your alternate apple id - somewhere? it is does not allow that on the current apple id screen.

Comment: What do you want, change the email of your apple id?

Comment: No, I don't need to change the email.  I need to change the ALTERNATE Apple ID.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

You can change the alternate id only. Simply [SIGN IN](https://appleid.apple.com/signin) or go to appleid.apple.com and sign-in.

Once you sign in the 1st Tab will autonomously be selected for you : 'Name, ID and Email Addresses', if not select that one.

You will see a list of all the info related to that tab.

On the bottom you will see the alternate email address, below that section you will see the same thing but it will be editable. You can, add, delete, or edit any current additional emails to your primary apple ID email.

[image]

Again you can ***NOT*** alter your primary email address.

Comment: website not found for applied.apple.com - or did you mean the appleid site?

Comment: @hellergang it was a typo - autocorrect actually, typing from my iPhone. Yes it's appleid.apple.com or you can click on the hyperlink in my answer

Comment: Actually whether you can change the Primary Appleid varies.  If your primary appleid is an email address ending in `@me.com` `@icloud.com` or at `@mac.com` you can not change the primary email. If your appleid was created using a non-apple email address, then the primary email address of the appleid can be changed.

Comment: Sorry, soulshined: Your answer does exactly NOT help. You described how to change an email adress. Changing the "Alternate Email Adress" does not change the "Alternate Apple ID" ! It seems that it is either not at all possible to change the Alternate Apple ID or at least it is not possible, if it ends on @me.com, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to change the email address of your apple id. After a quick search on google I came on [this](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202667) page from [apple.com](http://apple.com)

This should be detailed enough to help you solve your problem.